# Cloning native resources

Tags: vb.net, resources, clone

**This question is related to Visual Basic .NET 2010**

I'm trying to clone the "native" resources of one file and applying them to another. I tried enumerating the resource names and then applying them with UpdateResource.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class ResourceCloner
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint:="EnumResourceNamesW", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function EnumResourceNames(ByVal hModule As IntPtr, ByVal lpszType As String, ByVal lpEnumFunc As EnumResNameProcDelegate, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint:="EnumResourceNamesW", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function EnumResourceNames(ByVal hModule As IntPtr, ByVal lpszType As Integer, ByVal lpEnumFunc As EnumResNameProcDelegate, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function
    <DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint:="BeginUpdateResourceA", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function BeginUpdateResource(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)> ByRef pFileName As String, ByVal bDeleteExistingResources As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
    <DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint:="EndUpdateResourceA", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function EndUpdateResource(ByVal hUpdate As Integer, ByVal fDiscard As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function UpdateResource(ByVal hUpdate As IntPtr, ByVal lpType As String, ByVal lpName As String, ByVal wLanguage As UShort, ByVal lpData As IntPtr, ByVal cbData As UInteger) As Boolean
    End Function
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function FindResource(ByVal hModule As IntPtr, ByVal lpName As String, ByVal lpType As String) As IntPtr
    End Function
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function LoadLibraryEx(ByVal lpFileName As String, ByVal hReservedNull As IntPtr, ByVal dwFlags As UInt32) As IntPtr
    End Function
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, EntryPoint:="FreeLibrary")> _
    Public Shared Function FreeLibrary(ByVal hModule As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function
    Private Delegate Sub EnumResNameProcDelegate(ByVal hModule As IntPtr, ByVal lpszType As IntPtr, ByVal lpszName As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr)

    Private Target_file As String
    Private Clone_file As String

    Sub New(ByVal Target_file As String, ByVal Clone_file As String)
        Me.Target_file = Target_file
        Me.Clone_file = Clone_file
    End Sub

    Public Sub Clone()
        Flush(Target_file)
        Dim dll_hInst As IntPtr
        dll_hInst = LoadLibraryEx(Clone_file, 0, &H200)
        If Not dll_hInst.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
            EnumResourceNames(dll_hInst, 0, AddressOf EnumResNameProc, IntPtr.Zero)
            FreeLibrary(dll_hInst)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub EnumResNameProc(ByVal hModule As IntPtr, ByVal lpszType As IntPtr, ByVal lpszName As IntPtr, ByVal a As IntPtr)
        Dim Resource As IntPtr = FindResource(hModule, lpszName, lpszType)
        'Dim x = LoadLibraryEx(Target_file, 0, &H200)
        Dim FileHandle As IntPtr = BeginUpdateResource(Target_file, False)
        Dim Success As Boolean = UpdateResource(FileHandle, lpszType, lpszName, 0, a, Len(a))
        EndUpdateResource(FileHandle, 0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Flush(ByVal File As String)
        EndUpdateResource(BeginUpdateResource(File, 1), 0)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Some explanation: Target_file is the file I want to apply the cloned resources **to**, and Clone_file is the file I want to clone the resources **from**.

I tried my code and it doesn't throw any errors, it's just, nothing seems to happen.

Comment: You need to make a **lot** more noise when one of these functions fails.  Throw a Win32Exception.  Particularly for EndUpdateResource().  You don't know why it doesn't work because you never check if it worked.

Comment: Okay, I tried what you suggested, but it didn't throw any errors.

Comment: Actually, the error is probably in UpdateResource where I try to pass IntPtr arguments to a string parameter. Still confused about the whole thing though.